# Diffrence between overflow-x and overflow

Tags: css, scroll

What is the diffrence between `overflow-x: hidden` and `overflow:hidden;`?

What I know is that overflow-x: hidden; disable horizantal scroll but when I use it, it does not work only with firefox so I change it with overflow and it works perfectly.

Comment: the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) says `overflow-x` should work for firefox

Comment: The real question seems to be why `overflow: hidden` does not work in some situation. You should show a testable example (HTML and CSS code) and make it clear whether “does not work only with firefox” means that it works in other browsers, but not in Firefox, or something else.

Answer (score 3):

overflow-x and overflow-y are the same (horizontal and vertical) BUT:
The computed values of ‘overflow-x’ and ‘overflow-y’ are the same as their specified values, except that some combinations with ‘visible’ are not possible: if one is specified as ‘visible’ and the other is ‘scroll’ or ‘auto’, then ‘visible’ is set to ‘auto’. The computed value of ‘overflow’ is equal to the computed value of ‘overflow-x’ if ‘overflow-y’ is the same; otherwise it is the pair of computed values of ‘overflow-x’ and ‘overflow-y’

Checkout this web: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow-x

Answer (score 2):

In CSS 2.1 there was only [`overflow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow):

> This property specifies whether content of a block container element
>   is clipped when it overflows the element's box. It affects the
>   clipping of all of the element's content except any descendant
>   elements (and their respective content and descendants) whose
>   containing block is the viewport or an ancestor of the element.

However, the [CSS basic box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/) introduced [`overflow-x` and `overflow-y`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#nameoverflow-x), and redefined [`overflow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#nameoverflow) to be a shorthand of them:

> These properties specify whether content is clipped when it overflows
>   the element's [content area](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#content). It affects the clipping of all of the
>   element's content except any descendant elements (and their respective
>   content and descendants) whose containing block is the viewport or an
>   ancestor of the element. ‘[Overflow-x](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow-x)’ determines clipping at the
>   left and right edges, ‘[overflow-y](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow-y)’ at the top and bottom edges.
>
> ‘[Overflow](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow0)’ is a shorthand. If it has one keyword, it sets both
>   ‘[overflow-x](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow-x)’ and ‘[overflow-y](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow-y)’ to that keyword; if it has
>   two, it sets ‘[overflow-x](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow-x)’ to the first and ‘[overflow-y](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow-y)’ to
>   the second.

Answer (score 0):

- `overflow: hidden;` hides both horizontal and vertical scrollbars.
- `overflow-x: hidden;` hides horizontal scrollbars.
- `overflow-y: hidden;` hides vertical scrollbars.

Make sure you are setting the property to hide horizontal scrollbars like so:

```
body {
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```