# Sticky header - overflow-x : auto with overflow-y : unset, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar, overflow

I am working on making the header row of table stick at the top as long as the table component is in the view port.

I have a table inside a table wrapper div which is inside a parent div. I need to control the horizontal scroll bar using table wrapper div by setting its overflow to auto. For vertical scroll, I want table wrapper to inherit the scroll bar from parent div by setting table wrapper's overflow to inherit or unset.

Skeleton code - https://codepen.io/shubham_687/pen/powZpNb

HTML Changes

```
<div class="parentWrapper">
    <div class="tableWrapper">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="sticky-header">num</th>
                    <th class="sticky-header">alpha</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>A</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <p> Paragraph </p>
    <p> Paragraph </p>
    <p> Paragraph </p>
    <p> Paragraph </p>
    <p> Paragraph </p>
    <p> Paragraph </p>
    <p> Paragraph </p>
    <p> Paragraph </p>
    <p> Paragraph </p>
</div>
```

CSS Changes

```
.sticky-header {
  z-index: 7;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}

.parentWrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
}

/*
This is working right now, in order to make header row sticky, have to unset both scroll bars from table wrapper
*/
.tableWrapper {
  overflow-x: unset;
  overflow-y: unset;
  position: relative;
}

/*
 Need this so that sticky header can work and also table wrapper can control horizontal scroll bar by setting max width later
*/
/*
.tableWrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: unset;
  position: relative;
}
 */
```

it seems overflow-x : auto overwrites the overflow-y value and control for both scroll bar goes to table wrapper div and we can access those scroll bar setting max-height and max-width for table wrapper.

If I set bother overflow-x and overflow-y to unset, both horizontal and vertical scroll bar gets controlled by parent div.

So my question is if it is possible to have overflow-x : auto with overflow-y: unset or is this combination not supported?

Comment: `overflow-y` is not an inherited property to begin with. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit: _"For non-inherited properties, [`inherit`] specifies a behavior that typically makes relatively little sense and you may consider using initial instead, or unset on the all property."_

Comment: But you can probably work around your issue, by using a CSS variable to provide the value instead, I am guessing. (Guessing, because your question so far lacks an actual proper [mre].)

Comment: @CBroe, Please find the code here - https://codepen.io/shubham_687/pen/powZpNb

Comment: I really can't tell what you actually want to achieve, based on that example.

Comment: @CBroe, I want the header row to stick on the top (as long as the table is in view) as we scroll down in the parent wrapper

Comment: As I said, you can not "inherit" the value from the parent, because this is not an inherited property to begin with. And `unset` in that case, resets it to its default - which is `visible`. So I am guessing your actual problem might be with the computed values here, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28376925/1427878 - `visible` automatically _becomes_ `auto`, if the other one (referring to the individual `overflow-x` and `-y` properties here) is set to `auto` or `scroll`.

Comment: Thank you for this valuable input. It makes a lot of sense now!